# React - insertion of third party script tag inside render rather than page head causes app failure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

I'm writing a React component to use Mozilla's [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) project to render a document in HTML.  I've gotten it working successfully when the example's Create-React-App project includes

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.527/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

in the index.html head block.  If I remove it and insert it in the component `render` method, the application breaks.  Is there a way to add a `<script>` tag to the body of the application

### Background

According to the [examples](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples), there are two ways you can add a document to a page: render each page with the `canvas` tag, or use `pdfjs-dist/web/pdf-viewer.js`

### Code

Following the [Webpack examples](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/webpack) (since this is a React project), I came up with the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import pdflib from 'pdfjs-dist';
import {PDFJS} from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer'
import 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css';

export default class PDF extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        pdflib.PDFJS.workerSrc = require('file-loader!pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker');
        this.file = props.file;
        this.pdfViewer = null;

        this._containerId = 'viewer_container';

        this.pagesInit = this.pagesInit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadDocument();
    }

    pagesInit(e) {
        this.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';
    }

    _loadDocument() {
        const container = document.getElementById(this._containerId);
        this.pdfViewer = new pdflib.PDFJS.PDFViewer({
            container: container
        });

        container.addEventListener('pagesinit', this.pagesInit);

        const loadingTask = pdflib.getDocument(this.file);
        loadingTask.promise.then((document) => {
            this.pdfViewer.setDocument(document);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={this._containerId}>
                <div className="pdfViewer" id="viewer"></div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

However, for a reason unknown to me, I need to include the build of `pdf.js` in the head of the index page of the application so it is loaded before the bundle.

```
<!--
  manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
  homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
-->
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.527/pdf.min.js"></script>
<!--
  Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
  It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
  Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
```

Without it, the document will not render.  This seems directly related to script ordering.

Part of the convenience of an external React component is its self-contained, and this script requirement means this component certainly is not self contained.

I've attempted to use [`react-async-script-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-script-loader) to wrap the component in a Higher Order Component and retrieve the script, but the same error happens.

Is there another solution I should look at?

Comment: is https://github.com/yurydelendik/pdfjs-react any better for you?

Comment: @async5 Much!  Thanks!